# Animate a Background image using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if anyone can see why my code is not working for this?

Firstly this is my CSS for the Banner Div.

```
#banner
      { 
        width: 960px; 
        height: 200px; 
        margin: auto; 
        background:url('http://lifewallpaperz.com/images/2015/counter- strike/counter-strike-04.jpg') repeat-y scroll left top;
      }
```

This is my javascript code

```
var scrollSpeed = 70;
var step = 1;
var current = 0;
var imageWidth = 960;
var headerWidth = 200; 

var restartPosition = -(imageWidth - headerWidth);

 function scrollBg(){
 current -= step;
 if (current == restartPosition){
 current = 0;

 $('#banner').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
 }


 var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
```

Can anyone see any errors with my code?. I previously had it working and made a change in the CSS to say -x instead of -y but then it stopped working :( Can anyone help me?

Many Thanks

Comment: can you create a fiddle demo?

Comment: There do seem to be some JS errors - http://jsfiddle.net/ybw3og46/ - Try using JSHint